# Gave up waiting for root file system device in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, suspend, uuid

My laptop has ubuntu 22 and windows OS installed. Ubuntu was logged in. Mistakenly, I forgot to plug the charger and battery drained. When I tried to restart, I can see grub menu, but then it loads for a bit longer than usual then this screen appears...

```
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   -  Check rootdelay= (did the same wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules: ls /dev)
A:ERT!   UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I can get into system using Try/Install Ubuntu bootable drive. I have 3 drives in linux

- `/boot` - /dev/nvme0n1p5 - UUID=yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy
- `/root` - /dev/nvme0n1p6  UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (Gave up screen is giving id of this drive)
- `swap` - /dev/nvme0n1p7

I also tried to replace drive uuid with `/dev/nvme0n1p6` on grub menu by pressing 'e' and updating the line starting with 'linux' but of no use. Also tried to add 'noresume' in the end of this line, nothing worked. I can't even see any drive if I run `ls /dev` command on Gave up screen

Now how can I regain the access to actual system?